# How to move a REST resource?

Tags: rest

I'm trying to move a resource from `/buckets/1` to `/buckets/2` such that:

#### Initial state

- /buckets/1 = foo
- /buckets/2 = HTTP 404

#### Final state

- /buckets/1 = HTTP 301 to /buckets/2
- /buckets/2 = foo

What's a RESTful way of asking the server to move a resource in this manner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move resource in RESTful architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512677/move-resource-in-restful-architecture)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answering my own question:

- For the sake of this discussion let's assume that we are storing "balls" in buckets
- The first thing to notice is that a ball's life-cycle is not determined by its containing bucket (moving a ball from one bucket to another does not delete the old ball). As such we should promote balls to a top-level resource: `/balls`
- REST seems to work best in terms of symbolic links as opposed to inline values, so instead of `GET /buckets/1` returning the value of the ball in the bucket let's have it return the URI of the ball instead.

We can then move balls as follows:

```
(examine original state)
GET /buckets/1: "balls = {'/balls/1'}"
GET /buckets/2: "balls = {}"
GET /balls/1: "bucket = /buckets/1"

(move ball into bucket #2)
PUT /balls/1: "bucket = /buckets/2"

(examine new state)
GET /buckets/1: "balls = {}"
GET /buckets/2: "balls = {'/balls/1'}"
GET /balls/1: "bucket = /buckets/2"
```

End-result: the ball's identity remains consistent as it moves across buckets and (most importantly) this operation is atomic.

Comment: I like your answer, but I don't understand your mention of atomicity. It seems to me that you have two requests. Won't the world be in a strange state in between the two requests? (The ball resides in 2 buckets, which isn't really the state you want to be in).

Comment: How do you tell the different between PUT that move a ball between bucket and a PUT that update the ball?

Comment: @Ido, if a user PUTs a bucket which differs from the current value then it is a move. Keep in mind that you could move a ball and update its state at the same time.

Comment: This works fine if you send a full resource that has an updated id. If you just want to move the resource on the server the PUT request would have to somehow account for that.

Answer (score 4):

1. `GET /buckets/1`
2. `DELETE /buckets/1`
3. `PUT /buckets/2 {data returned by #1}`

That doesn't make the server `301`, though. The alternative would be to use the [WebDAV `MOVE` method](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html#METHOD_MOVE), i.e. by creating your own `@MOVE` annotation using the `@HttpMethod` annotation:

```
import ...;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("MOVE")
public @interface MOVE {}
```

but doing so breaks REST's architectural principle of using HTTP as a uniform interface ([RESTful Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=_jQtCL5_vAcC&lpg=PP1&dq=restful%20java%20with%20jax-rs&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Comment: Interesting answer but not the correct one because, by your own assertion, the above is not RESTful.

Comment: Which isn't RESTful, using `@MOVE`?

Comment: @Matt, you wrote: "but doing so breaks REST's architectural principle of using HTTP as a uniform interface." Aren't you implying that @MOVE isn't RESTful? Please clarify. Also, I don't think that a combination of DELETE and PUT is RESTful in the sense that you're implying that /buckets/2 refers to a different object from /buckets/1 which is not true.

Comment: Did you read the HTTP Method Extensions section in RESTful Java?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, I did. My understanding is that they support defining new methods so long as they are well-established in the community (versus everyone defining their own custom methods). I don't understand the text of your answer though. Are you saying that introducing @MOVE is RESTful or not?

Comment: I found a very interesting discussion thread where Fielding discusses @MOVE here: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/5874 and http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/5867

Comment: Nice find. My take on the matter is that there isn't a really RESTful way to do "move" because "move" isn't a RESTful operation. I think of the RESTful operations having direct mappings to, for example, SQL operations (`GET -> SELECT`, `POST -> INSERT`, etc.) and there's certainly no "move" SQL operation.

Comment: The guys on rest-discuss seem to agree with you. They argue that relationships between resources belong in the resource representation (think HTML links) as opposed to something you need to retain using a MOVE command. That seems to fly in the face of what HTTP 301 is all about though, doesn't it? How do I prevent clients from mistakenly believing that a resource has been deleted when it was really moved?

Comment: How about the following approach? Every resource has a canonical URI. Instead of adding the canonical resource into the bucket, we add a symbolic link. When a resource is moved, we delete the symbolic link from one bucket and add a new symbolic link into the second bucket. By instructing clients to only communicate with the canonical URI we guarantee that clients will never mistakenly believe that a resource has been deleted. In fact, an even better solution to promote the resource to the top-level. Instead of adding /buckets/1 into /buckets we should add /foo/1 instead.

Comment: This isn't very efficient when moving a huge resource, as it requires `2n` of network traffic (where `n` is the resource's size). (ie: a 2GiB file requires 4GiB of network transfer).

Answer (score -1):

1. Create original resource:

   `PUT /bucket/1`
2. Call server procedure that responsible for moving resources:

   `POST /bucket/1/move-to/2`
3. Original resource path now should return Moved status code:

   `GET /bucket/1 HTTP 301`
4. Resource now should be available on new path:

   `GET /bucket/2 HTTP 200`